# Autocomplete ComboBox

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

Kind time, I apologize in advance for verboseness.

Not so long ago I performed a test task on creating an autocomplete list of cities.
From the functional:

1. When you enter the first character, the list is filtered. The first
   item in the list is highlighted. The optimal number of rows in the
   list is 5. If the list can be very large after filtering, this
   number can be increased to 20.
2. If processing a request to build a list takes longer than 0.5
   seconds, show the loader at least 1 second. If the list is already
   open, and when a response has a delay - we show the loader, the list
   remains in the same state before the update.
3. If a server error occurs, we show the error message and the update
   button.
4. If there is no match for the input, we show the corresponding test.
5. Loss of focus without selecting an item from the list If nothing is
   found, show error
6. If the list did not manage to load, we show an error
7. If the entered value is symbolically coincident with the value in
   the directory, if the focus is lost, we select it
8. When the focus is received, the value entered is highlighted

Also some things are not quite right or not done at all and I now wondered how it would be possible to implement it.

In the second point, the preloader is shown only until the data is fully loaded and is removed after loading the data.
In point 7, I can not understand how to compare immediately the data from the array and the full word.
And it's interesting how to make the active class when I click on the result because I did not succeed in clearing the class before adding the class.

I would like to hear the advice of more experienced programmers about improving the code.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOMoby?editors=0011)

```js
let homeworkContainer = document.querySelector('#homework-container'),
    filterBlock = document.getElementById('filter-block'),
    filterInput = homeworkContainer.querySelector('#filter-input'),
    filterResult = homeworkContainer.querySelector('#filter-result'),
    filterList = homeworkContainer.querySelector('.filter-list'),
    info = homeworkContainer.querySelector('.info-block'),
    reoladBtn = document.createElement('div'),
    filtrFocusOut;

function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ('withCredentials' in xhr) {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != 'undefined') {
        // XDomainRequest for IE.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
    }
    
    return xhr;
}

function loadAndSortTowns() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        let url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smelukov/citiesTest/master/cities.json',
            preloader = document.createElement('div'),
            xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);

        preloader.className = 'input__preloader';

        if (!xhr) {
            alert('CORS not supported');
            
            return;
        }
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        filtrFocusOut = true;
        filterBlock.appendChild(preloader);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            let resp = xhr.response;

            preloader.remove();
            filtrFocusOut = false;

            if (xhr.status === 200 && xhr.readyState === 4) {
                resp.sort(function(a, b) {
                    if (a.name > b.name) {
                        return 1
                    }

                    return -1
                });
                resolve(resp);
            } else {
                reoladBtn.innerHTML = 'reolad';
                reoladBtn.className += 'reolad-btn';
                filterList.appendChild(reoladBtn);
                filterResult.innerHTML = 'Something went wrong. Check your internet connection and try again'

            }
        };

        xhr.send();

    })
}

function checkFilterStatus (array, count) {
    if (array.length === 0) {
        info.innerHTML = 'Not what is not found';
        filtrFocusOut = true;
    } else {
        filtrFocusOut = false;
        filterInput.parentNode.classList.remove('filter-erore');
        if (count > 1) {
            info.innerHTML = 'Showing ' + count + ' in ' + array.length + ' Found cities. Please request again to see the rest'
        } else {
            info.innerHTML = ''
        }
    }
}

function isMatching(full, chunk) {
    full = full.toLowerCase();
    chunk = chunk.toLowerCase();
    if (full.substr(0, chunk.length) === chunk) {
        return true;
    } 
    
    return false;
    
}

filterInput.oninput = function(e) {
    e.target.parentNode.classList.remove('filter-erore');

    loadAndSortTowns().then(function (data) {
        let value = e.target.value.trim(),
            htmlText = '',
            checkArray = [],
            count = 0;

        if (value.length > 0) {
            filterList.classList.add('is--show');
            for (let i= 0; i<data.length; i++) {
                if (isMatching(data[i].name, value)) {
                    checkArray.push(data[i].name);
                    if (checkArray.length <= 5) {
                        count++;
                        htmlText += '<div id=' + data[i].Id + ' ' + 'class="result__item">' + data[i].name + '</div>';
                    }
                } else {
                    checkFilterStatus(checkArray, count, htmlText)
                }
            }

        } else {
            filterList.classList.remove('is--show');
            info.innerHTML = '';
        }

        filterResult.innerHTML = htmlText;

    });
};

filterList.onclick = function (e) {
    if ( e.target.className.indexOf('result__item') === 0) {
        filterList.classList.remove('is--show');
        filterInput.value = e.target.innerHTML;
    }
};

filterInput.onchange = function (e) {

    if (filtrFocusOut) {
        e.target.parentNode.classList.add('filter-erore');
        info.innerHTML = 'Select a value from the list';
    }
};

filterInput.onfocus = function(e) {
    e.target.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);
};

reoladBtn.onclick = function () {
    loadAndSortTowns();
};
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8"; .main { width: 480px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 50px; font: 14px “SegoeUI”, sans-serif; color: #404040; } #filter-block { position: relative; width: 400px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 5px; line-height: 20px; } #filter-block .autocomplite-fild:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { opacity: 0.8; } #filter-block .autocomplite-fild:focus::-moz-input-placeholder { opacity: 0.8; } #filter-block .autocomplite-fild:focus:-moz-input-placeholder { opacity: 0.8; } #filter-block .autocomplite-fild:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { opacity: 0.8; } .name-fild { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; } .autocomplite-fild { width: 100%; padding: 5.5px 0; padding-left: 10px; } .autocomplite-fild:focus { border: 2px solid #5199db; } .input__preloader { width: 22px; height: 22px; position: absolute; top: 4px; right: 4px; background: url("./gif-load.gif") no-repeat; background-size: cover; } .filter-list { display: none; position: absolute; top: 32px; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; max-height: 300px; z-index: -1; -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=15, Direction=0, Color=#000000)"; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=15, Direction=135, Color=#000000); } .result__item { display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #000; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 0; padding-left: 10px; } .result__item:first-child { background: #5199db; color: #fff; } .result__item:active { background: #f1f1f1; } .info-block { padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 11px; } .filter-erore .autocomplite-fild { border: 2px solid #e3071c; } .filter-erore .info-block { color: #e3071c; } .filter-erore .filter-list { box-shadow: none; -ms-filter: none; filter: none; } .reolad-btn { background: #5199db; color: #fff; } .is--show { display: block; } .result { margin-bottom: 5px; }
```

```html
<div id="homework-container">
<div id="filter-block">

    <input type="text" placeholder="start write" id="filter-input" class='autocomplite-fild' onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)">

    <div class="filter-list">
        <div id="filter-result"></div>
        <div class="info-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```